# Login working in localhost but login not working in remotely yii

Tags: php, yii

I am able to login in `localhost` but when I moved files to server it's not working I tried to login in server but it's not working but when I tried in local login working is there is any solution for that? This is my config files have a look on that:

```
<?php

Yii::setPathOfAlias('chartjs', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../extensions/yii-chartjs');
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'HireRedson',
    'preload' => array('log', 'chartjs'),
    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.components.fb.*',
        'application.components.twitteroauth.*',
        'application.components.linkedin.*',
        'application.components.linkedin-new.*',
        'application.components.plaxoauth.*',
        'application.components.gplus.*',
        'application.components.imageresize.*',
        'application.controllers.*',
        'application.components.yiinfinite.*',
        'application.modules.digitalinterviews.models.*',
    ),
    'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => '123456',
            'ipFilters' => array('192.168.2.*'),
        ),
        'digitalinterviews' => array(),
    ),
    'components' => array(
        'chartjs' => array('class' => 'chartjs.components.ChartJs',),
        'Smtpmail' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
            'Host' => "smtp.gmail.com",
            'Username' => 'dasdadsadsa@gmail.com',
            'Password' => 'dasdasdsad',
            'Mailer' => 'smtp',
            'Port' => 465,
            'SMTPAuth' => true,
            'SMTPSecure' => 'ssl',
        ),
        'mailNew' => array(
            'class' => 'YiiMail',
            'transportType' => 'smtp',
            'transportOptions' => array(
                'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
                'username' => 'test@nouvohire.com/jobsite/',
                'password' => '',
                'port' => 2525,
            ),
            'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
            'logging' => true,
            'dryRun' => false
        ),
        'mail' => array(
            'class' => 'YiiMail',
            'transportType' => 'smtp',
            'transportOptions' => array(
                'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
                'username' => 'test@nouvohire.com/',
                'password' => '',
                'port' => 2525,
            ),
            'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
            'logging' => true,
            'dryRun' => false
        ),
        'campaignmail' => array(
            'class' => 'YiiMail',
            'transportType' => 'smtp',
            'transportOptions' => array(
                'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
                'username' => 'test@dsfsdfdsfds.com',
                'password' => 'ssssssss',
                'port' => 2525,
            ),
            'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
            'logging' => true,
            'dryRun' => false
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        ),
        'session' => array(
            'autoStart' => true,
            'savePath' => 'sessions',
            'cookieMode' => 'allow',
            'cookieParams' => array(
                'path' => '/',
                'domain' => '.nouvohire.com/jobsite/',
                'httpOnly' => false,
            ),
        ),
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'caseSensitive' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                'test_url/<test_url:\w+>' => 'digitalinterviews/recruitment/globalinterviewstart/', //############for interview master
                'digitalinterviews/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'digitalinterviews/<controller>/<action>', //########for interview master
                'digitalinterviews/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'digitalinterviews/<controller>/<action>',
                '' => 'site/index',
                'r/<id:\d+>' => 'Jobs/Redirect',
                'j/<id:\d+>' => 'Jobpage/Redirect',
                'app/<id:\d+>' => 'App/Index',
                'site/feed/<site:\w+>' => 'Site/Feed',
                'maintenance.html' => 'site/UnderMaintenance',
                'digitalinterviews/Test/scriptcam.lic' => 'digitalinterviews/invitecandidates/getLicense/',
                'digitalinterviews/questions/Add_question/scriptcam.lic' => 'digitalinterviews/invitecandidates/getLicense/',
                'digitalinterviews/recruitment/testWebcam/scriptcam.lic' => 'digitalinterviews/invitecandidates/getLicense/',
                'digitalinterviews/Candidatetest/onlinetest/scriptcam.lic' => 'digitalinterviews/invitecandidates/getLicense/',
                'digitalinterviews/questions/editQuestion/scriptcam.lic' => 'digitalinterviews/invitecandidates/getLicense/',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=test.com;dbname=testdb',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'teeee',
            'password' => 'asdasdsadsadsadsa',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'authManager' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID' => 'db',
        ),
        'errorHandler' => array(
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
        'log' => array(
            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error, warning',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'ePdf' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
            'params' => array(
                'mpdf' => array(
                    'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.mpdf.*',
                    'constants' => array(
                        '_MPDF_TEMP_PATH' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime'),
                    ),
                    'class' => 'mpdf',
                ),
                'HTML2PDF' => array(
                    'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.html2pdf.*',
                    'classFile' => 'html2pdf.class.php',
                )
            ),
        ),
        's3' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.s3.ES3',
            'aKey' => 'asdsdssf',
            'sKey' => 'djdssadjajsdjksadjsahdkksajdjask',
        ),
        'file' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.file.CFile',
        ),
        'functions' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.s3.Functions',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hi ,and welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you tidy your code up so it's readable? you should probably take out all the commented lines, and tidy up the indentation so people can more easily see what you're doing. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you've tagged the question yii2, but it looks like you're using yii1. Can you check which you're using and delete the tag if appropriate?

Comment: I don't see anything in your config related to the problem. You should check application log and apache log for problems.

Comment: where can i find log file  in yii

Comment: Should be in protected/runtime http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention#directory

Comment: THERE IS NO FILES IN THAT FOLDER

Comment: Ah, then it might be a permission issue, be sure /assets, /protected/runtime have write access for the user running the webserver.

Comment: I made it 755 permissions

Comment: still not working login

Comment: @user5713661 I see you use `savePath` for sessions in your config. Make sure that this folder have permissions for write and read on server.

Comment: I set permission but still not working can we chat in chat session

Comment: check your `.htaccess` file and upload it with proper rules...

Comment: Check your database settings db name and password on server

Comment: Check your startup index.php file if there are IP adresses specified for access restrictions on test servers.

Comment: Did you check if the user you are trying to login to exists in your database?

Answer (score -1):

This could be a permission issue please check if **sure /assets, /protected/runtime** have write access for the user

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check :

- The DB exist in the remote server?
- The User that you try to connect en your db config have select permission?
- The user that you try to log in exists on the remote database?